# Dell G15 Integrated Camera is not working with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, dell, webcam, camera, integrated

On Ubuntu 22.04, Kernel 6.5.0-21-generic - the integrated camera does not work. This hasn't worked since I updated from Ubuntu 20.04 last year March.

Cheese shows "No device found"

Any idea on how I can troubleshoot and have the camera functional again, please?

Thanks in advance
Yatish

Comment: What is the camera detected as in `dmesg` on the working Ubuntu 20.04 LiveCD?

Comment: Try finding the camera in `lsusb` output and post here

Comment: Thanks for the replies - `lsusb` lists the USB devices. Currently, listing Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth, Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth and USB OPTICAL MOUSE - which are other devices I connected using USB previously ...

If I run `sudo dmesg | grep cam` , I get a few lines with `Product: Integrated_Webcam_HD` and `Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:6a09)`

On running `sudo dmesg`, there are few errors stating: 

 - `Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 2).`
 - `device descriptor read/64, error -71`
 - `unable to enumerate USB device`

Comment: According to https://askubuntu.com/a/1411791/1004020 it needs some kind of "software update". Does it work on a 23.10 LiveCD?